# Javascript variable inside a php foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The problem I'm having is quite simple in that each iteration of the foreach loop is over writing the previous javascript variable, I am not sure how to resolve this, and then what to call in the later function

```
foreach($variant->images as $image){
    echo '
    <div class="product-thmb-group">
        <img id="hikashop_child_image_'.$char_id.'" class="hikashop_child_image" src="' . $this->image->uploadFolder_url . $image->file_path . '" alt="hikashop_child_image_' . $char_id . '"  />
        <span class="product-thmb-title">'.$char_name.'</span>
    </div>
    <script>
        char_id = \''.$char_id.'\';
    </script>';
}


<script>
    jQuery('#hikashop_child_image_24').click(function() {
        jQuery('#hikashop_product_characteristic_13').val(char_id).chosen().change();
        jQuery('#hikashop_product_characteristic_13_chzn').trigger("chosen:updated");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: PHP = ServerSide, JS = ClientSide - the ONLY chance to inject PHP into JavaScript is at Page-Load - after that you'll need to use either AJAX or Postbacks to communicate between the two

Comment: I think it's not quite clear what you want to accomplish

Comment: what i am trying to accomplish is changing the value of a chosen select box when an image is clicked on with the idea being that each select option and each image share a char_id

Comment: ok i think there is an easier way, but as a novice i need to figure this out I already have #hikashop_child_image_24 so could i not just get the id of the object clicked and strip the #hikashop_child_image part and assign that as the char_id variable? this seems simpler than anything else but am not sure of the proper syntax to accomplish this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing but thank you for the input

```
jQuery('*').click(function(e) {
    var char_id = e.target.id;
    e.stopPropagation();
    var id = char_id.slice(-2);
    jQuery('#hikashop_product_characteristic_13').val(id).chosen().change();
    jQuery('#hikashop_product_characteristic_13_chzn').trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could update your javascript variable inside your php. if you make ajax requests . or just reload your page with ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by generating GENERIC HTML and leaving out all the ID selectors and markup-specific jQuery functions by doing something like this. It's probably not exactly what you need, but you get the idea.

```
foreach($variant->images as $image){
    echo '
    <div class="product-thmb-group">
        <img class="hikashop_child_image" data-chzn=' . $char_id . ' src="' . $this->image->uploadFolder_url . $image->file_path . '" alt="hikashop_child_image_' . $char_id . '"  />
        <span class="product-thmb-title">'.$char_name.'</span>
    </div>
}
```

JS:

```
jQuery('.product-thmb-group img').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).val(char_id).chosen().change();
    jQuery(this).data('chzn').trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```